# Which of the following commands accept the --preserve-root flag?

Tags: bash

Which of the following commands accept the --preserve-root flag?

```
chgrp
chmod
rm
rsync
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for cmd in chgrp chmod rm rsync; do 
    man "$cmd" | grep -q "preserve-root" && echo "$cmd"
done
```

**OR**

```
$ for i in chgrp chmod rm rsync; do $i --help | grep -q '\-\-preserve\-root' && echo $i; done
chgrp
chmod
rm
```

Comment: Why should it? That wasn't asked for - this merely answers "which of the following commands..." If there's a question like "how can I look at the man page" or "what does the man page say about it", it may deserve a different answer.